# Is it worth to change the style of my webapp's menu?

Tags: navigation, menu, mobile-web, mobile-application, sidebar

Is there a difference regarding UX between those both styles of **mobile** menu display:
(one appears one the left side, other on the full width vertically)

This one above is the kind of navbar that [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) provides:

[image]

On the other hand, Facebook mobile app, for instance, uses this left-style:

[image]

As my application is based on Twitter Bootstrap 3 (HTML5), I use natively the first solution.
However some lambda users (non-UX guys at all) came to me and said:
 "Hey! You should try to put the menu on the left, it's the trend !!"

But I strictly don't see the extra benefit...
What could it be?  Should I really change it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd want this to be on the TOP RIGHT.

[image: Facebook Navigation on iOS App]

Facebook app on iOS uses the TOP RIGHT area not sure why the Web does not follow the same approach. For me, the RIGHT side is better since for right-handed people (considering it a majority), having the menu on the top right area makes for a more accessible location.

1. Using right hand, it's easier to reach the top right from your thumb compared to top left.
2. Top left is usually reserved for BACK buttons on mobile applications which makes for a consistent behaviour when that space is not invaded by the MENU.

I checked Bootstrap 3 and it uses the same convention.

[image: Bootstrap Menu Placement - Top Right]

It places the MENU on the right. My guess is for the same usability reason, it makes accessing navigation easier for right-handed people. Probably you are using older Bootstrap.

Comment: And what about the Twitter Bootstrap design ? ( first solution evoked)

Comment: Hi @Mik378, I checked Bootstrap too and have updated the answer to reflect the same. Again, from a usability point of view, yours first & second approach are the same. The only difference is Facebook uses Offcanvas approach which just let's the user know they can go back. 
Regardless of the approach you choose, they should not impact the usability of the menu.

Comment: Understood :) I think I will stay with the bootstrap solution for now, since already made. Thanks a lot :)